# Curl, Fatal, could not upload, can't open file. What gives?

Tags: curl, ftp

```
> QUIT
< 221-Goodbye. You uploaded 1104 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
< 221 Logout.
* Closing connection #0
Tue Aug  9 14:30:16 MST 2011: [2 of 5] Uploading 'client/Tech Contracts/Tech Contract PDF2.psd'
curl: Can't open 'client/Tech'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Tue Aug  9 14:30:16 MST 2011: fatal: Could not upload, exiting...
Tue Aug  9 14:30:16 MST 2011: Releasing lock
```

I've gotten this one countless files now. It's getting annoying as it keeps stopping the upload. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, your file names contain spaces (in the directory name), and these names aren't escaped properly. How do you call curl?

Comment: git-ftp push -scope.....I just noticed the space issue RIGHT after posting. Though that's an inconvenience to have to rename. I was reading that newer versions of curl may support spaces, do you know if it's true?

Comment: all versions of curl supports spaces in file names, but you need to provide the file name(s) using the proper quotations

Comment: curl does support spaces - you just have to quote them properly, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444705/bash-script-for-downloading-files-with-curl (don't know about git-ftp, though)